# Jump out of the "main Latex file" in gvim

Tags: latex, vim

I am using gvim to edit LaTex file. With some wrong keys, at the bottom line, the system asks me to input "main LaTeX file:". No matter what I input, I simply couldn't get out of this. I have to stop this session and reopen gvim again. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Did you installed some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to press escape a few times, then `:q!<Enter>`

Comment: Thanks Zak. :-) See my comment in perreal's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `q` enter, or `x` enter, or only press the enter key

Comment: Thanks perreal. :-) I will try. The problem is that I can't repeat that "wrong keys", probably because of my removing a plugin. I think it will work. Thanks a lot! (to encourage "young/new" guys, I choose his answer).